# Jquery SPLIT field names

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

Hello i want to explode  input:names to array with [] as delimiter

Example
the name recipe[0][recipe_photo] i want to convert to object ['recipe',0,'recipe_photo']

```
$('input', form).each(function () {
  var arr = $(this).data("name").split('');
  console.log(arr);
});

<form>
<input name='recipe'/>
<input name='recipe[]'/>
<input name='recipe[0][recipe_photo]'/>
<input name='recipe[1][recipe_photo]'/>
</form>
```

Comment: `$('input').each(function () {
  var arr = $(this).prop("name");
  console.log(arr);
});`

is this what you want

Comment: i don't need this. I want to explode the names of the fields to Array.

Answer (score 1):

here my solution

```
var parts = arr.split(/[[\]]{1,2}/);
console.log(parts); // ["recipe","0","recipe_photo",""]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
    function go(str)
    {
      if (!str) return;
      var arr= str.split(/[\[\]]+/g).filter(function(v){return v!==''});
      return 'object['+arr.join(',')+']';
    }

console.log(go('recipe[]')); //object[recipe]
console.log(go('recipe[0][recipe_photo]')); //object[recipe,0,recipe_photo]
console.log(go('recipe[1][recipe_photo]')); //object[recipe,1,recipe_photo]
```

[**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/juwote/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstood your question, but I tried my best to give you a solution.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/u20bjvya/) it is.

```
var arrayWithNames = [];
$('input').each(function () { arrayWithNames.push($(this).prop("name"));});
```

As you can see, I push every 'name' property to the array 'arrayWithNames'.